# How do I put a user input int as array length in Java?

Tags: java

If I ask the user for input, how do I put it as the length of an array?

Example:

```
String teamnum = Input.nextLine();

int teams[]=new int[teamnum];
```

Comment: Look at [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the input as a integer also that's not the way you declare arrays. Try this:

```
String teamnum = Input.nextLine();
 int newnum = Integer.parseInt(teamnum);
 int[] teams = new int[newnum];
```

Comment: You can declare arrays by doing `int teams[] = ...`. I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: Yes I suppose that's true but it is not good practice as you said so I thought it'd be better.